# When Stopping Package Event Handler Triggers

Tags: sql-server, ssis, event-handling

I have a package that writes to an audit log with a startdatetime, enddatetime, and success bit. When the package is running the startdatetime is populated. There are times when I need to stop the package, for testing or if it is causing server resource limitations.
When I click stop package in the sqlagent, is there a way for this to trigger writing to the enddatetime and the success bit?

I tried using a OnVariableValueChanged Event Handlers, but those don't trigger the sp to write to the audit log. I tried using the and OnQueryCancel Event Handler, but that seems to check repeatedly if the package should stop, not if it did. So it is slowing down the execution.

Comment: When you stop a package you *literally* stop it; it doesn't go into an error or cancel path. As a result you can't have it do *something else* when you tell it to stop. It's much like going to Task Manager and hitting "End Task" on a process in the Details pane. You might be better off building a process that stops the agent task and then `UPDATE`s your table to set the end time and success of the current unfinished job.

Answer (score 0):

If the package is running as a job, you can use T-SQL to stop the job. You could use a stored procedure like `sp_stop_job` to do this. You must specify the job_name or job_id of the job running the SSIS package.

Then you can create a T-SQL command that updates the audit log with the end date/time and success bit. You must know the unique identifier or any other criteria for the specific package run you are logging.

Your script for the 1st part can be like below :

```
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job N'Your SSIS Package Job Name';
```

Then to add the Update Audit Log Step, your script is something like below :

```
 UPDATE YourAuditLogTable
 SET enddatetime = GETDATE(),
     successbit = 0
 WHERE packageid = 'Your Package ID';
```